# Pass value from controller to the blade and dynamically add a number to it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I want to add one number in the case of adding a new line by jQuery, and this number is added to the id that I pass from the controller to the blade

[image]

Here is the js Code in the blade

```
$('#add4').click(function(){
  var rowCount = $('#table_field4 .trr').length + 1;
  var html = '<tr>'+'<td><input type="text" value="{{$serialNumberUnits+'rowCount'}}"></td></tr>';
  $('#table_field5').append(html);
});
```

And here is the variable that I passed from the controller to the blade

```
$serialNumberUnits = DB::table('product_unit_prices')->latest('id')->first()->id + 1;
return  view('admin.addProduct',compact('serialNumberUnits'));
```

Comment: Your problem is that you've put `{{$serialNumberUnits+'rowCount'}}` in there, which PHP will try to interpret. If you'd put the braces around only the PHP variable and ended the JS string before that, it would work fine. Simply viewing the page source to see what is being output should be a first troubleshooting step.

Comment: e.g. `var html = '<tr><td><input type="text" value="' + ({{$serialNumberUnits}} + rowCount) + '"></td></tr>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **$serialNumberUnits** will be a string, try to convert to an integer using **parseInt()** and do the calculations

```
 $('#add4').click(function () {

    let rowCount = $('#table_field4 .trr').length + 1;

    /**
     * Keeping the passed value in a variable 
     * to keeping it clean
     */
    const serialNoUnits = "{{$serialNumberUnits ?? 0}}";

    /**
     * Parsing into integer and adding 
     */
    let newValue = parseInt(serialNoUnits) + rowCount;

    /**
     * Adding value into field
     */
    let html = '<tr>' + '<td><input type="text" value="'+newField+'"></td></tr>';
    $('#table_field5').append(html);
  });
```

Comment: I followed the same method that you used, and indeed it gave me the desired result. Thank you very much for your help, knowing that I used it in this way

```
 let html = '<tr>' + '<td><input type="text" value="'+newValue+'"></td></tr>';
    $('#table_field5').append(html);
```

Comment: `serialNoUnits` is only a string because because you put quotes around  the PHP value.